# AppAuth Unknown url scheme

Tags: android, redirect, appauth

I have an issue with handling redirecting from webview back to app using AppAuth. I keep getting net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME. In my build.gradle I declared manifest placeholder in defaultConfig

```
manifestPlaceholders= [
    'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'com.example.mc2017'
]
```

and in manifest I got RedirectUriReceiverActivity

```
<activity android:name="net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="com.example.mc2017"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

where com.example.mc2017 should be the scheme I'm listening for. Could anyone point me to where the mistake is ?

Answer (score 0):

1- you should use `${...}` schema for placeHolders but anyway you never use placeholder in your manifest.

2- you can use a schema for your url for example `myApp://com.example.mc2017` in this case you manifest become like this:

```
<activity android:name="net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data 
       android:host="com.example.mc2017"
       android:scheme="myApp"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```